# what does x[1] mean?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

N = len(sortedAverageList)
x = np.arange(1,N+1)
y = [x[1] for x in sortedAverageList]
width = 1

labels = [x[0] for x in sortedAverageList]
```

What does `[x[1] for x in sortedAverageList]` in the coding above?
What does `x[1]` mean?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=subscription#subscriptions  ,,, item one of x

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been marked as *too broad*  or *unclear*. To me it seems pretty clear and quite narrow. The PO has provided the necessary information and it can be answered in a couple of sentences. I agree that the question is a very basic one, but I haven't found a similar question of which this could be a duplicate. After all, SO is not about closing questions, but about helping other people, independent of the level of programming they currently are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sortedAverageList` is a sequence containing another sequence with at least 2 elements, 
`[x[1] for x in sortedAverageList]` will give you a list of the second element in each of those sequences.

Example:

```
sortedAverageList  = [[1,2],[5,6],[7,8]]
print ([x[1] for x in sortedAverageList] )
#prints [2,6,8]
```

For each of the lists `[1,2]`, `[5,6]`, `[7,8]`, `x[1]` chooses the respective second element. `x[0]` would choose the first and `x[2]` would not work because the lists only have two elements.

Note that the `x` in `[x[1] for x in sortedAverageList]` has nothing to do with the `x` you define in the line above. Instead it is the variable inside the for loop to which the elements of `sortedAverageList` are repeatedly assigned.

I would recomment to study some [basic python tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) before continuiung with more advanced tasks like plotting.